# Lottie file animation doesn't show

Tags: javascript, lottie

After rendering after effects file to `data.json` and `lottie.js` file even I add script and linked lottie file in website animation doesn't show up but in demo it comes. Can you folks check whether I have done some thing wrong with the coding.

```
<script src="lottie.js"></script> 
<script>
var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container:document.getElementById('bm'),
    renderer:'svg',
    loop: true,
    autoplay:true,
    path:'data.json'
})
</script>
```

Comment: There is not enough info here for us to help. Does the path `data.json` resolve? Are there any errors on the page?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.